# Slice list in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, chunks

I need to slice a list using python 3.7, and slice should contains two elements, if at the end we got one elements (like below),  that's last element should go to previous part.

```
def solution(A):
    l = len(A)
    size = 2
    for i in range(1, len(A), size):
        print(A[i:i+2])

solution([4,2,2,5,1,5,8,9])
```

Output:

```
[2, 2]
[5, 1]
[5, 8]
[9]
```

Desire output:

```
[2, 2]
[5, 1]
[5, 8, 9]
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def solution(A):
    l = len(A)
    size = 2
    groups = [ A[i:i+size] for i in range(1, len(A), size) ]
    if len(groups[-1]) < size:
       groups[-2].extend(groups.pop())
    for x in groups:
        print(x)
```

Works for every value of size, not just 2.

Answer (score 1):

```
def solution(A):
    l = len(A)
    size = 2
    for i in range(0, len(A), size):
        if l%2!=1 and i==l-3:  #if the length is odd and i is the third last
            print(A[i:i+3])
            break
        else:
            print(A[i:i+2])

solution([4,2,2,5,1,5,8,9])
```

Comment: This seems to hardcode `+3` and `+2` when the user uses a variable called `size` for the length of the output.

Comment: Is it better now?

Answer (score 1):

You could just check if the next loop iteration will go too far, and if so print the entire list and stop.

Like so

```
def solution(A):
    l = len(A)
    size = 2
    for i in range(1, len(A), size):
        print(i)
        if i+2*size > len(A):
            print(A[i:])
            break
        else:
            print(A[i:i+2])
```

Answer (score 1):

This function will do the trick (I'm not very happy with it, and I'm sure that there must be a better way out there, but it will do for now).

```
def listSlicing(raw_list, slice_length):

    # Get the number of elements that will be left out when the list is sliced 
    extra_elements = len(raw_list)%slice_length 

    # Create a list of slices. Do not go to the last element
    sliced_list = [raw_list[i:i+slice_length] for i in range(0, len(raw_list)-extra_elements, slice_length)] 

    # Access the last item of the sliced list and append the extra elements to it
    if extra_elements == 0:
        return sliced_list # No need to change the last value
    else:
        sliced_list[-1].extend(raw_list[-extra_elements:]) 
        return sliced_list

l = [4,2,2,5,1,5,8,9,10]
listSlicing(l, 2)
# Will return [[4, 2], [2, 5], [1, 5], [8, 9, 10]]
```

In case there is only space for one slice (for example, assume a slice_length of 5 instead of 2), the function will return only a single list, as, after creating the first slice, the remaining 4 items (5, 8, 9, 10) will be appended to the first slice itself, effectively returning the same list again.

Answer (score 0):

```
def func(a, size):
    c=[]
    if size==0 or size<0:
        return []
    if size>=len(a):
        return a 
    c = [a[i:i+size] for i in range(0,(len(a)//size)*size,size) if i%size==0] 
    c[-1].extend(a[(len(a)//size)*size:])
    return c

a = [4,2,2,5,1,5,8,9, 10]
print(func(a, 2))
print(func(a, 111))
print(func(a, 9))
print(func(a, 5))
```

output

```
[[4, 2], [2, 5], [1, 5], [8, 9, 10]]
[4, 2, 2, 5, 1, 5, 8, 9, 10]
[4, 2, 2, 5, 1, 5, 8, 9, 10]
[[4, 2, 2, 5, 1, 5, 8, 9, 10]]
```